# 10 Commandments and Non-Jews

Tags: aseres-hadibros

Are there any sources that discuss the non-Jew's connection to and/or obligations regarding the 10 Commandments (i.e. the [10 Dibrot](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.1-14?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

---

I've heard from rather learned (if not conventional) people claim that the 10 Commandments are the moral code for the whole world, but the only sources inside that I've seen discuss non-Jew's obligations tend to only bring up the 7 Noahide laws. In reality, the Christians tend to teach them as morally binding, and so do the Muslims, and many claim that they are important for inter-faith dialogue.

So what is the Torah stance on this? Shabbat seems like the most obvious one that would be questionable, and they were given at Sinai, so this makes them very personal between Hashem and the Jewish people. On the other hand, many of them seem like they would fall under 7 Noahide laws themselves, and they do carry a universal application and usefulness to morality for all humanity.

Comment: Have you seen the commentary Heichal HaBrachah from the Komarna Rebbe? He discusses how each of the mitzvot are rooted in the individual letters of the Ten Commandments. In this context, you might also enjoy reviewing Sefer Mitzvot HaShem which is a broad explanation of each of the 7 commandments of the Noahides and their relationship to 613 commandments.

Comment: @YaacovDeane perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I was just listening to Rabbi Tatz talk about how the mitzvot are all rooted in the 10 Dibrot. I have known about that since I was a teenager and it's incredible.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a.6?lang=he&with=all

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a.11?lang=he&with=all

Comment: I heard from R' Yaakov Weinberg z"l that he was on a bus with the Mayor of Baltimore, who challenged him: "Which of the Ten Commandments does not apply to non-Jews?!" He said, "Shabbos", of course. The mayor didn't like that, "I can't respect anyone who says that the Sabbath is not for all mankind." Rav Weinberg commented to us with a smile, "I should have said, לא תחמוד!"

Comment: "and so do the Muslims" They're commanded in the sabbath?

Comment: @robev I don't understand your question. They consider the 10 commandments as important to some degree or another. They keep a Thursday night Sabbath but I am not an expert.

Comment: Our sages are clear that keeping Shabbath is forbidden for a non-Jew, even if they keep it on another day.